# Toggle and Fade Effects Sequentially

Tags: jquery

I'm looking to toggle between slide-down then fade-in and fade-out then slide-up effects in jQuery. Is it possible to do something like this with `toggle`? I currently have:

```
<a href="#" id="toggle">more</a>

<div id="about">
  <p id="info">...</p>
</div>

<script>
  $('#toggle').click(function() {
    $('#about').toggle('fast', function() { $('#info').fadeIn(); });
  });
</script>
```

But it only works for the initial click. Can two functions be added to click that are toggled between? Does a way of doing the above without keeping track of state variables exist? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:

```
$("#info").toggle(
  function () { $("#about").toggle('fast', function () { $("#info").fadeToggle('fast'); }); },
  function () { $("#info").fadeToggle('fast', function () { $("#about").toggle('fast'); }); }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use is() and :visible to check the state.
Try this:

```
<script>
  $('#toggle').click(function() {
        var about = $("#about")
        if(about.is(':visible')){
            $('#about').toggle('fast', function() { $('#info').fadeOut(); });
        }
        else{
            $('#about').toggle('fast', function() { $('#info').fadeIn(); });
        }

  });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I was looking at a different order though (slide-down then fade-in; fade-out then slide-up). I managed to figure it out but appreciate the answer!

Answer (score 1):

You can consider FadeToggle

http://api.jquery.com/fadeToggle/

```
<script>   
$('#toggle').click(function() {     
    $('#about').toggle('fast', function() { 
      $('#info').fadeToggle(); 
    });   
}); 
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I was looking at a different order though (slide-down then fade-in; fade-out then slide-up). I managed to figure it out but appreciate the answer!

Comment: nw, I couldnt' have guessed the order based on the original ;) but glad you didnt' have to go through the check hide stuff.